# C# equivalent to Java's continue <label>?

Tags: c#, java

Should be simple and quick: I want a C# equivalent to the following Java code:

```
orig: for(String a : foo) {
  for (String b : bar) {
    if (b.equals("buzz")) {
      continue orig;
    }
  }
  // other code comes here...
}
```

---

***Edit***:
OK it seems there is no such equivalent (hey - Jon Skeet himself said there isn't, that settles it ;)). So the "solution" for me (in its Java equivalent) is:

```
for(String a : foo) {
  bool foundBuzz = false;
  for (String b : bar) {
    if (b.equals("buzz")) {
      foundBuzz = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (foundBuzz) {
    continue;
  }
  // other code comes here...
}
```

Comment: Hope dies last: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/869 and here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6340889-allow-the-c-break-statement-to-terminate-sever (cannot vote though).

Comment: C# should get a "continue {label}" and "break {label}" feature one day - see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/869 and vote

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't believe there's an equivalent, I'm afraid. You'll have to either use a boolean, or just "goto" the end of the inside of the outer loop. It's even messier than it sounds, as a label has to be applied to a statement - but we don't want to do anything here. However, I think this does what you want it to:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("i={0} j={1}", i, j);
               if (j == i + 2)
               {
                   goto end_of_loop;   
               }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("After inner loop");
            end_of_loop: {}
        }
    }
}
```

I would *strongly* recommend a different way of expressing this, however. I can't think that there are many times where there isn't a more readable way of coding it.

Comment: It's a bit surprising that C# has `goto`, but not `break/continue <label>`.

Comment: C# is more true to its C roots than Java is. It also has structs and pointers!

Comment: wait a second: @JonSkeet was *AFRAID* of this? how am *I* supposed to be in this case?

Answer (score 11):

Other posibility is to make a function with the inner loop:

```
void mainFunc(string[] foo, string[] bar)
{
  foreach (string a in foo)
    if (hasBuzz(bar))
      continue;
  // other code comes here...
}

bool hasBuzz(string[] bar)
{
  foreach (string b in bar)
    if (b.equals("buzz"))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I like this better, because such loops in functions often have a good semantic (=> good name) of their own and are thus reusable.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.Net, you could just have one `while` loop and one `for` loop and then `exit` the desired scope level.

In C#, maybe `break;` ?

That might break out of the inner loop and allow the outer loop to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the simple "continue" keyword...  However, not being a Java guy I don't really get what the code snippet is trying to achieve.

Consider the following, though.

```
foreach(int i in new int[] {1,2,3,5,6,7})
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
        continue;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());    
}
```

The continue statement on line 4 is an instruction to continue with the loop at the next value.  The output here would be 1,3,5 and 7.

Replacing "continue" with "break", as follows,

```
foreach(int i in new int[] {1,2,3,5,6,7})
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
       break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());    
}
```

will give the output 1.  Break instructs the loop to terminate, most commonly used when you want to stop processing when a condition is met.

I hope this gives you some of what you were looking for, but if not, feel free to ask again.

Comment: thanks, but i do know the difference between continue and break. ;-) the thing is: i have two nested loops. and if a certain condition in the inner loop occurs, i want to "continue" the outer loop.

Comment: Sorry - did't mean to teach you to suck eggs - The fault is mine for not reading the question adequately...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i< foo.Length -1 ; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j< bar.Length -1; j++) {
    if (condition) {
      break;
    }
    if(j != bar.Length -1)
        continue;
    /*The rest of the code that will not run if the previous loop doesn't go all the way*/
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is the rest of the code is AFTER the nested loop, not in it.

Comment: whoops i just noticed in my first example i had the line wrong for the "//code here" comment. sorry.

Comment: You could just set a flag before breaking, and check the flag after the loop.  And if you really want your code to be formally 'structured' you set j = bar.Length rather than using 'break'.

Comment: j = bar.Length would run the current loop to the end, this is not what is intended ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in C# and I'm know this is an old question, but came up the following solution for this issue:

Usage:

```
const string topLoopLabel = "topLoop";

Loop.ForEach(fooList, (fooItem, index, next) => 
{
    // ...
    Loop.For(0, (i) => i < bar.Length, (i) => i++, (index, next) => 
    {
        // ...
        if (condition) 
        {
            next(topLoopLabel);  
        }
        // ...
    });
    // ...
}, topLoopLabel);
```

Under the hood:

```
static class Loop {

    public delegate void Continue(string? label = null);

    public delegate void IndexedIterationHandler(int index, Continue next);

    public delegate void ListIterationHandler<T>(T item, int index, Continue next);

    private static Continue next = (label) => {
        throw new CancelledIterationException { Label = label };
    };

    public static void For(int initialIndex, Func<int, bool> indexCondition, Func<int, int> iterator, IndexedIterationHandler iterationHandler, string? label = null)
    {
        for (int i = initialIndex; indexCondition(i);)
        {
           OnIteration(() => iterationHandler(i, next));
           i = iterator(i);
        }
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(IList<T> list, ListIterationHandler<T> iterationHandler, string? label = null) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            OnIteration(() => iterationHandler(list[i], i, next));
        }
    }

    /*
     * other loop types can be defined here
     */

    private static void OnIteration(Action loopBody)
    {
        try
        {
            loopBody();
        }
        catch (CancelledIterationException e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Label) && !String.Equals(e.Label, e))
            {
                throw;
            }
         }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    class CancelledIterationException : Exception
    {
        public required string? Label { get; init; }
    }
}
```

Pros:

- no goto or multiple return statement
- no temporary variable
- different loops can easily combine
- easy to understand
- not required to add label to each loop

Cons:

- as you see under the hood exception used to modify program flow which is antipattern
- if you call the next fn in the top loop which string param does not equal the top loop label then the exception won't be catched.