# How do a break a loop outside a try/catch from within it?

Tags: c#, while-loop, try-catch, break

I am working on a simple class project for school to experiment with inheritance and other essentials in c# but I am having trouble with a certain part. I believe I need a try catch within an unconditional while loop to be certain the user enters the data in the correct form but I also need to be able to break out of the loop from within the error handling code. I have put a comment beneath the code that is giving me problems.

```
class Program : students
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        students stu = new students();

        Console.Write("Number of students are you recording results for: ");
        int studNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        stu.setNoOfStudents(studNum);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int a = 0; a < studNum; a++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}. Forename: ", a + 1);
            stu.setForname(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("{0}. Surname: ", a + 1);
            stu.setSurname(Console.ReadLine());
            while (0 == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}. Age: ", a + 1);
                    stu.setstudentAge(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    Console.Write("{0}. Percentage: ", a + 1);
                    stu.setpercentageMark(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    stu.fillArray();

                    break;
                    // This is the block that gives me problems; the
                    // while loop doesn't break.
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This must be a number.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting an error because its within a try/catch but the while(0 == 0) loop is never broken so the for loop cannot iterate the command. Can someone give me a solution to this?

Comment: It does break, but the for loop will continue and execute the while loop again.

Comment: @KevinKal it doesn't look like that on my screen, a remains at 0. if the for loop iterates shouldn't the increment increase a?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359436/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-continue-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `break`should take you out of the `while loop`. If you step through, what happens at the `break`?

I suggest using `Int.TryParse`:

```
bool input_ok = false;
int input;
while (! input_ok)
{     
     Console.Write("{0}. Age: ", a + 1);
     input_ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
     if (input_ok)
        {
            stu.setstudentAge(input)
        }
}
```

the `while` loop should keep running until you get something that will fit.
All that inide the `for loop`.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually catching the method fillArray()

Comment: So it never got to the `break`, but the catch as a bit obscure. I hope you worked it out.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead of a break

```
bool stop = false;
while (!stop)
{
    try
    {
        // Time to exit the loop
        stop = true;
     }
     catch { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is **misleading**. `break` is indeed the right way (no flags and fake exceptions needed) and it **works** (breaks the `while` loop in your case). The only branch in your code that keeps looping is your `catch` block, but that I guess is intentional (otherwise the `while` loop makes no sense).

Comment: could you explain why the catch block is doing an infinite loop?

Comment: apparently because there is no `break` statement inside, so the control flow continues. the only exit point for an infinite `while` loop are `break`, `return` and uncatched `throw`s.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this approache

Add fakeexception

```
public class FakeException: Exception { }
```

sample code:

```
try
{

      //break;
      throw new FakeException();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   if(ex is FakeException) return;
   //handle your exception here
}
```

Comment: exceptions for flow control is considered an antipattern and considered no better than using `goto`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why Use them for when something exceptional happens, not in the normal course of events. Also, throwing exceptions is expensive in terms of performance.